# Selecting only element currently being hovered with jquery and toggle visibility of next element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with class `.MathBox` the very next element is `.ypnLeftRight`
Whenever user hovers on `.MathBox`, `.ypnLeftRight` visibility toggles. This works perfectly when there is a single `.MathBox` element but when there are many such elements jquery selects all the elements with the class `.Mathbox` and all `.ypnLeftRight` elements toggle simulteneously.

How to toggle just the div with class `.ypnLeftRight` present right after the currently hovering `.MathBox` element?

```js
$('.MathBox').after('<div class="ypnLeftRight"><div class="left-button">&laquo;</div><div class="right-button">&raquo;</div></div>');

$('.right-button').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.MathBox').animate({
    scrollLeft: "+=200px"
  }, "slow");
});

$('.left-button').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.MathBox').animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=200px"
  }, "slow");
});

$('.MathBox , .ypnLeftRight').hover(function() {
  $('.ypnLeftRight').show();
}, function() {
  $('.ypnLeftRight').hide();
});
/*
  $('.MathBox , .ypnLeftRight').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.ypnLeftRight').show();
  }, function(){
    $(this).find('.ypnLeftRight').hide();
  });*/
```

```css
.MathBox {
  width: 100%;
  border: dashed 1px #dddddd;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ypnLeftRight {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 1.5em
}

.ypnLeftRight>div:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="postContentItem">
  1<br/>
  <div class="MathBox">
    x^2 + 3x + 30 -32x^3 +16x^4 -x^2 -55x + 60= 0<br/>text{This is the required equation obtained by solving the quadratic equation by factorization method.
  </div>
  222<br/> 222
  <br/>1<br/>
  <div class="MathBox">
    x^2 + 3x + 30 -32x^3 +16x^4 -x^2 -55x + 60= 0<br/>This is the required equation obtained by solving the quadratic equation by factorization method.
  </div>
  222<br/> 222
  <br/>
</div>
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$('.MathBox , .ypnLeftRight').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('.ypnLeftRight').show();
}, function(){
  $(this).find('.ypnLeftRight').hide();
});
```

Comment: You are placing the new content after Mathbox but looking inside Mathbox with the `find()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ypnLeftRight is always hidden you do not need a hover on it. The hover applies only on .MathBox. Secondly... you need to target the .next() of hovered over .MathBox  like this:

```
$('.MathBox').hover(function(){
  $(this).next('.ypnLeftRight').show();
}, function(){
  $(this).next('.ypnLeftRight').hide();
});
```

The intent of the OP is to use buttons inside .ypnLeftRight while hovering .MathBox. The code above fails to do so because the DIV are not enclosed together in a parent div. Below is the code that serves the OP's purpose.

Enclose the .MathBox div in a div

```
<div class="MathBoxParent">
  <div class="MathBox">
    x^2 + 3x + 30 -32x^3 +16x^4 -x^2 -55x + 60= 0<br/>text{This is the required equation obtained by solving the quadratic equation by factorization method.
  </div>
</div>
```

Then use following code

```
$('.MathBoxParent').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('.ypnLeftRight').show();
}, function(){
  $(this).find('.ypnLeftRight').hide();
});
```

Comment: I need hover over .ypnLeftRight because it contains buttons to scroll the content of .MathBox. Your method works but .ypnLeftRight isn't initially hidden it hides after the user has hovered over .MathBox.

Comment: so add another hover method just for the .ypnLeftRight because what you are saying means that on hover of .ypnleftright it will hide itself which doesn't make any sense. You want to do something else when hovering on .ypnLeftRight. But show/hide .ypnLeftRight when hovering on MatchBox.

Comment: adding $('.ypnLeftRight').hide(); before your code hides the buttons by default. Problem mitigated! Now for hovering on .ypnLeftRight, When user hovers on .MathBox, the buttons in .ypnLeftRight appear, but now when user moves cursor over .ypnLeftRight, it means user is no longer hovering on .MathBox thus the buttons hide. This renders the buttons useless as user just can't use them. Thanks for showing interest and spending your time in helping me out. There's no emoji for salute so here's Vulcan Salute... 

Comment: The solution for that is to wrap both .MathBox and .ypnLeftRight in a parent div and attach the hover to that div. And instead of hiding in Javascript you should do display: hide in .ypnLeftright css.